# How to embed $S_{n-1}$ into $S_n$ in $n$ ways?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. How to embed $S_{n-1}$ into $S_n$ in $n$ ways?

Comment: Well, do you know one way to do it to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in how many ways can you pick $n-1$ different elements from the set $\{1,2, \cdots , n-1, n\}$?